# In "X-Men Origins: Wolverine", why did Stryker want to apply adamantium to Logan?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

Can't understand why Stryker went to all the effort to apply adamantium to Logan, if all he wanted to do was create weapon X/Deadpool?

Was there some reason why he had to lace Wolverine with adamantium first, then Deadpool later?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He used Wolverine as a test to make sure the healing factor in Wolverine was strong enough to survive the adamantium injection. He then took the healing factor and added it to Deadpool. Deadpool was to be the ultimate mutant weapon, with multiple level 4 mutant powers.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool#Film):

> [has] been transformed... into... a mutant killer who possesses other mutants' powers, including Scott Summers' optic blasts, John Wraith's teleportation, Chris Bradley's technopathy, Wolverine's healing factor, and a pair of extendable blades resembling Wilson's prized swords. He is referred to by Stryker as "the Deadpool" because the compatible powers of the other mutants have been "pooled" together into one being.

Comment: In the comic book, Weapon X was to make, essentially, a mutant-hunter/cape-killer, and James Howlett/Logan was one of the best candidates known at that time. Deadpool (Wade Wilson) was apart of a Deadpool, in which he took a healing process to heal his incurable cancer, and got a pizza face and insanity in return.